# How to find the matrix of a transformation relative to standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $b_1=(-1,3)$ and $b_2=(1,-2)$ which make a basis for $\mathbb R^2.$ If
$$
T(b_1) = 6b_1 + 7b_2 \quad\text{and}\quad T(b_2) = 3b_1 + 8b_2,
$$
find the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis $E$ for $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: Are $b_1$ and $b_2$ written with respect to the standard basis?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $b_i$ consists of the columns $[6 \  7]^T$ and $[3 \   8]^T$. If $B$ denotes the matrix transforming a vector given in the standard basis into a vector in the basis $b_i$ then the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis will be
$$ B^{-1}TB$$

It is not difficult to find $B$. I would like to leave it to you.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've written, the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B=\{b_1,b_2\}$ should be
$$
[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix} 6 & 3 \\ 7 & 8 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
So to write the matrix with respect to the standard basis, it would be helpful to find the change of basis matrix, call it $P$, taking a matrix written with respect to $B$ to one written with respect to the standard basis.